# Symfony3.4 monolog bundle not writing to custom channel file

Tags: symfony, monolog

When i add a custom channel in monolog the file not creating and not logging in to file.

**my config_dev.yml**

```
debugchannel:
            level: debug
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/debug_%kernel.environment%.log"  
            channels: ['debugchannel']
            formatter: application_debug.formatter.debug
```

The file not creating.

Comment: Have you excluded the channel from the main debugger using `[..., '!debugchannel']`?

Comment: Is debugchannel a top-level handler? How do you use the logger service?

Answer (score 1):

When i give this way as they said in their documentation .Its not writing any data to redis and not find any error.

```
monolog:
    channels: ["debugchannel"]
    handlers:
        debugchannel:
            level: debug
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/debug_%kernel.environment%.log"
        main:
            type: stream
            path: '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log'
            level: debug
            channels: ['!event','!debuggchannel']
```

Comment: Try adding `channels: ['debugchannel']` also in debugchannel handler.